# ProFTPd returns "530: Login incorrect."

Tags: centos, ftp, centos7, proftpd

There are some weeks that I don't use the FTP server, and now I have tried to connect but it's returning this error. I did some "yum update", but I don't know what else has changed since then.

When I use the "proftpd -nd10" command, it returns:

```
...
    2018-12-07 03:22:37,259 server.example.com proftpd[5938] 127.0.0.1: Failed binding to ::, port 21: Address already in use
    2018-12-07 03:22:37,259 server.example.com proftpd[5938] 127.0.0.1: Check the ServerType directive to ensure you are configured correctly
    2018-12-07 03:22:37,259 server.example.com proftpd[5938] 127.0.0.1: Check to see if inetd/xinetd, or another proftpd instance, is already using ::, port 21
    2018-12-07 03:22:37,259 server.example.com proftpd[5938] 127.0.0.1: Unable to start proftpd; check logs for more details
```

When I use the "netstat -putan | grep :21" command, it returns:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      5937/proftpd: (acce
```

If I stop the proftpd service, the port 21 becomes available. If I start again, the port became used again.

Here my config:

```
ServerType          standalone
ServerName          "server.example.com"
ServerIdent         on "FTP Server ready."
ServerAdmin         hostmaster@example.com
DefaultServer           on

# VRootEngine           on
DefaultRoot         ~ !adm
# VRootAlias            /etc/security/pam_env.conf etc/security/pam_env.conf

Port                21
PassivePorts            30000   35000

AuthPAMConfig           proftpd
AuthOrder           mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

UseReverseDNS           off

User                nobody
Group               nobody

MaxInstances            20
UseSendfile         off
LogFormat           default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat           auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"

ExtendedLog             /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth

#<IfDefine TLS>
  TLSEngine         on
  TLSRequired           on
  TLSRSACertificateFile     /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd/server.example.com.crt
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd/server.example.com.key
  TLSCertificateChainFile   /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd/server.example.com-intermediate.crt  
  TLSCipherSuite        ALL:!ADH:!DES
  TLSOptions            NoCertRequest NoSessionReuseRequired
  TLSProtocol                   SSLv23
  TLSVerifyClient       off
  #TLSRenegotiate       ctrl 3600 data 512000 required off timeout 300
  TLSLog            /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
  <IfModule mod_tls_shmcache.c>
    TLSSessionCache     shm:/file=/var/run/proftpd/sesscache
  </IfModule>
#</IfDefine>

<IfDefine DYNAMIC_BAN_LISTS>
  LoadModule            mod_ban.c
  BanEngine         on
  BanLog            /var/log/proftpd/ban.log
  BanTable          /var/run/proftpd/ban.tab

  BanOnEvent            MaxLoginAttempts 2/00:10:00 01:00:00
  BanControlsACLs       all allow user ftpadm
</IfDefine>

<Global>
  Umask             022
  AllowOverwrite        yes

  <Limit ALL SITE_CHMOD>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
</Global>
```

To be sure, I've changed my user's password, but nothing has changed.

Comment: What's the result of running:  fuser -n tcp 21 ?

Comment: returns "21/tcp: 5937"

Comment: Please grep the pid from : ps aux | grep 5937 or :  ps -ef | grep 5937

Comment: "nobody    5937  0.0  0.1 179332  3484 ?        Ss   04:44   0:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)"

Comment: Looks like proftpd is already running and listening on 21. Check the service status for proftp. Comment out the line starting "ftp" in /etc/inetd.conf and restart (killall -HUP inetd or something similar should do the trick) and try again. Please try accessing the server from a device using: ftp server.example.com and use the username and password you have configured. The logs will be written to : /var/log/messages . You can filter the logs to view only ftp related.

Comment: Also, please check auth log here: /var/log/proftpd/auth.log

Comment: auth.log:

server.exemple.com [10514] my-ipv4-here [07/Dec/2018:05:11:39 -0200] "USER isp" 331
server.exemple.com [10514] my-ipv4-here [07/Dec/2018:05:11:41 -0200] "PASS (hidden)" 530

Comment: Messages Log: Dec  7 05:20:32 server systemd: Starting ProFTPD FTP Server...
Dec  7 05:20:32 isp systemd: PID file /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Dec  7 05:20:32 server proftpd[11129]: 127.0.0.1 - ProFTPD 1.3.5e (maint) (built Wed Jan 31 2018 16:32:29 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
Dec  7 05:20:32 server systemd: Started ProFTPD FTP Server.

Comment: The file "/etc/inetd.conf" doesn't exist.

Comment: If the user account belongs to the list of accounts that are banned from accessing FTP (listed in ‘/etc/ftpusers’), then Proftpd would return a ‘530 login incorrect’ message. Few checks I could suggest include checking that file, changing the password of user and restarting proftd (using passwd and systemctl), ensure the shell assigned to the ftpuser is correct. Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/514742/proftpd-cannot-login-at-all-constant-530-error

Comment: Ok, I commented the line "AuthOrder   mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c" and now is working.

Comment: Sounds good! Please add it as a reply and mark it as solution, if you prefer. This might have been caused due to error in authentication modules / config.

Answer (score 1):

In the proftpd.conf, I commented the line:

```
AuthOrder   mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c
```

restarted the proftpd service and now is working.